# Does it matter which way a string method is used?

Tags: ruby, string, immutability, method-chaining

Codeacademy teaches that you can chain multiple methods together as such:

```
user_input.method1.method2.method3
```

However, in a later lesson they display some methods like this:

```
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!
```

I combined them:

```
user_input = gets.chomp.downcase!
```

When I use it this way:

```
user_input = gets.chomp.downcase!
if user_input.include? "s"
...
```

I receive an error `` "undefined method `include?'" ``. If I change it to the following, it works fine:

```
user_input = gets.chomp
user_input.downcase!
if user_input.include? "s"
...
```

I'm at a loss. I'm concerned whether or not this is a quirk with their console or if this is just how I should be doing it in Ruby. If someone could tell me which way is right, I'd appreciate it. If both are right, that's OK too.

Comment: just use `downcase` instead of `downcase!`?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in case you do not yet fully understand, assignment of values to variables are done through `=`, and that you could inspect what variable type it is by appending `.class` to anything.

Consider the following:

```
name = 'John'
puts name
# => John
puts name.class
# => String
```

Now, secondly, it should be noted that the return values of ALL methods are ALL different. But all of them can be identified into two types:

Methods that:

1. return self
2. return anything other than self

**Example for 1.**

-- methods that return self, which you could say methods that return the same type of object which in our specific case, a `String`

```
name = 'John'
puts name
# => 'John'
puts name.class
# => String

downcased_name = name.downcase
puts downcased_name
# => john
puts downcased_name.class
# => String

deleted_downcased_name = downcased_name.delete('h')
puts deleted_downcased_name
# => jon
puts deleted_downcased_name.class
# => String

# All of the above can be just simplified into:

deleted_downcased_name2 = 'John'.downcase.delete('h')
puts deleted_downcased_name2
# => jon
puts deleted_downcased_name2.class
# => String
```

Notice that `deleted_downcased_name` and `deleted_downcased_name2` are the same, because you could treat the chained methods as if you are chaining the return values which is 'John' -> 'john' -> 'jon'.

**Example for 2**

-- methods that return anything but self, which you could say methods that return a different type.

In our specific case, String's `downcase!` returns either a `String` or `NilClass` [(reference here)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#downcase-21-method)

- returning `String` if the string changes, or
- returning `nil` if string is already downcased to begin with (no change).

or another String's method: `start_with?` [(reference here)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#start_with-3F-method)

- returning `true` or `false`

This is where chaining of methods will not work (raises an error), when you try to use a String method as a chain to nil value.

Consider the following

```
name = 'mary' 
puts name
# => 'mary'
puts name.class
# => String

downcased_name = name.downcase!
puts downcased_name
# => nil
puts downcased_name.class
# => NilClass

downcased_name.delete('h')
# => This will raise the following error
# NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for nil:NilClass
```

The error above is because downcased_name is a type of `NilClass` where you are expecting it to be a type of `String`. Therefore you cannot chain any string method on it anymore. You can only chain `String` methods on a `String` type of value. Similarly, you can only chain `Number` methods on a `Number` type of value.

Whenever in doubt, you could always check the documentation to check what a method does, and what its return value and type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is with the bang method `downcase!`.

This is basically saying "mutate the original string so that it is downcase".
The important part is that this returns `nil`. As such you are actually calling `include?` on `nil`.

If you use the non bang method `downcase` instead, it is saying "downcase the previously chained thing but do not mutate the original". The key difference is that it returns the result rather than `nil`.

Here is an example:

```
str = "ABCD"
str.downcase!
=> nil

str
=> "abcd"

str = "ABCD"
str.downcase
=> "abcd"

str
=> "ABCD"  # Note str is still unchanged unless you set str = str.downcase
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Ruby!  While your apprenticeship at Codeacademy may be limited, you'll continue to refer to language API documentation throughout your career.  API documentation is a description of what the language (or a library) does for you.  In this case, you're using [downcase!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-downcase!) which, as one commenter points out, does not always return a String.  When it takes no action, it returns nil.  Nil is an Object in Ruby (like everything else), but the 'include?' method isn't defined for nil, which explains your error.  (It's one of the most common errors in Ruby, learn its meaning.)

So, in fact, what's breaking here isn't your method chain.  It's that one of the intermediate methods isn't returning a value of the type you expect (nil instead of some kind of String).

Answer (score 0):

Chaining non destructive methods like:

```
string.chomp.downcase...
```

has the advantage that the code is concise, but is not efficient if you are not interested in the original state of the object, and just want the final result because it creates intermediate objects during the chain.

On the other hand, applying destructive methods sequentially to the same object:

```
string.chomp!
string.downcase!
...
```

is more efficient if you do not need to keep the original state of the object, but is not concise.

Combining methods that may return an object of a different class (particularly `nil`) as:

```
string = gets.chomp!.downcase!...
```

is wrong because the result can become `nil` at some point in the chain.

Applying a potentially `nil`-returning method at only the last position as you did:

```
string = gets.chomp.downcase!
```

is still not useful if you expect `string` to always be a string, and can easily lead to an error as you did.

If you want to chain these methods in you example, perhaps you can do this:

```
user_input = gets.tap(&:chomp!).tap(&:downcase!)
if user_input.include?("s")
...
```